# SQL Query to become broader if there are limited results?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Am struggling to setup a query that can return additional results if the default query doesn't return enough.

For example:

```
Table:
Games
id
name
genre
console

Query:
Select * FROM [Games] WHERE genre='Driving' and console='PlayStation' LIMIT 0,5
```

If there are only 3 matching results, however, how could I adapt this query to show 2 results from other titles are in the same genre, but on any format?

E.g.

- Result 1: Genre = Driving / Console = PlayStation
- Result 2: Genre = Driving / Console = PlayStation
- Result 3: Genre = Driving / Console = PlayStation
- Result 4: Genre = Driving / Console = Any
- Result 5: Genre = Driving / Console = Any

Ideally in a single query, really stuck on setting this up!

Often most results will have the full set of 5, but sometimes there are only 3/4 and ideally I'd want to fill up the gap!

It should take the Genre + Console as priority first, then if limited results, omit console

Many thanks for any help!
J

Comment: Add OR condition and look  into ORDER BY FIELD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all rows regardless of the console, and then make sure the 'Playstation' results will appear first. That should do the trick:

```
Select * FROM [Games] WHERE genre='Driving' ORDER BY console<>'PlayStation' LIMIT 0,5
```